# I need to change video file extensions to mp4

Tags: php

I'd really appreciate someone doing this and also explaining what they did so I can understand it better.

Current Code:

```
            $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $extension = strtolower(substr ($name, strpos($name, '.') + 1));
            $newextension = 'mp4';
            $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

            $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

            $location = 'thelocation';

            if ($extension!==$newextension)
            {

            $extension = $newextension;
```

And if this can not be done, can someone inform me of a method on how to convert all none .mp4 files into .mp4 files serverside and if it is a automatic method or will have to be done manually.

Comment: You can't change easily the extension of the file. When you have a .avi or something else you have to convert it to the mp4 format.

Comment: @Stony - to be fair, he said he just wants to change the extension, not convert the format -_-

Comment: @admdrew: Its an upload... this means that he try to upload a video file... when you change the extension its not working.

Comment: if you just want to change just the extension of the file, there are more easy ways

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you're working with a temporary file, that needs to be copied from your temp directory to a final location such as /videos/video.mp4.

**So you'd change the extension as soon as you copy the file to the final location.**

First, you'd best use the [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function for retrieving the extension:

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Then, you'd filter the old extension from the filename, and append the new extension:

```
$newfilename = basename($_FILES['file']['name'], $extension).$newextension;
```

*Edit: instead of substr and strrpos, I've now used [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) with the extension as a suffix to retrieve the filename, which makes the code shorter and more readable.*

And copy the file to its new location:

```
copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'full/path/to/your/videos/'.$newfilename);
```